# extract a word from text considering punctuation

Tags: php

considering i have an offset marking the start of the word.. i need a method to get the size of that word considering all the sign of punctuation.

example:

```
$str = "my text bla bla-bla; hello! abc";
$offset = "22";  // start of hello
```

now i need a function that returns 5 considering hello is 5 chars.

this are some of punctuations may occur:

```
array(',','.',' ','-',"'",'"',';',':','?','!','|','/','\\','<','>')
```

i can do some hard parsing but i would like to write something more elegant

Comment: Um.  "hello" is 5 chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
function getWordSize($string, $offset = 0)
{
    $word = array();

    if (preg_match('~.{' . max(0, intval($offset)) . '}(\p{L}+)~u', $string, $word) > 0)
    {
        if (array_key_exists(1, $word) === true)
        {
            return strlen($word[1]); // bytes, or
            return strlen(utf8_decode($word[1])); // unicode chars
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
echo getWordSize('my text bla bla-bla; hello! abc', 21); // 5
```

However this doesn't handle offsets that cut words in middle, so:

```
echo getWordSize('my text bla bla-bla; hello! abc', 23); // 3
```

Comment: Wow I thought it would be simpler. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "my text bla bla-bla; hello! abc";
$offset = "22";  // start of hello

$chopped = substr($str,$offset);
preg_match("/[a-z]+/i",$chopped,$match);

$length = strlen($match[0]);
```

adapt `[a-z]` to the range of characters you consider a character (I didn't quite get your punctuation issue)

Comment: I can't adapt [a-z] so easly. Consider all accented words of various international language